# How to make a SVG diagram not truncate overflowing shapes?

Tags: css, html, svg

I have the following SVG shape which is created programmatically.
[image]

```
<svg style="overflow:visible; margin-left:121px; margin-top:39px; " height="206" width="327">
    <path d=" M 244.3,102.7  A 82.3,52 0,0 0,82.3 102.7 L 1.3,102.7  A 163.3,102.7 0,0 1,325.3 102.7 L 325.3,102.7 365.8,102.7 284.8,153.3 203.8,102.7 244.3,102.7  L 244.3,102.7 " x="1.5" y="1.5" style="fill:#92d050; stroke-width:3; stroke:blue; "></path>
</svg>
```

The fiddle for the above is : http://fiddle.jshell.net/VJL5W/

As one can see the right tip of the arrow is truncated because its path coordinates move outside the dimensions of the SVG.

One thing I can do is to traverse the `path` of the shape after it has been created and change the `height` and `width` of the `svg` tag according to the highest coordinate values I find, but it will make my code inefficient.

I tried `overflow:visible;` but it didn't work.

Is there anyway I can make the truncated part visible without changing the SVG's height and width?

Thanx in advance!!

**Note:** Interestingly `overflow:visible` is working on firefox but not in chrome based browsers. Also, my SVG is being created server-side from a corresponding VML image in a single parse conversion, so solutions that involve using any client side script can't be used by me.

Comment: If you have to do everything on the server side:  What are you generating the SVG with in the first place?

Comment: @ThomasW I am attempting a VML to SVG conversion.... i have the VML at the server side and I am converting it into an SVG.

Comment: btw why the down vote on the question?

Comment: No idea about the downvote. The question remains: What are you doing the conversion with? You will *have* to calculate the bounding box somehow. If you don't want to do that on the client as Robert Longson suggested, then you need to find a way with whatever server technology you are using.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because half of your requirements are in comments to answers. If you'd put them in upfront there would be a lot less time wasted.

Comment: @ThomasW I don't have to calculate the bounding box during my conversion because the VMLs that I try to convert already provide me the width and height of the shape. The point of contention is that if the path of a shape moves out of its dimensions the VML doesn't truncates it but sadly SVG does. So in most cases I can simple use the dimensions provided to me by VML but in a few cases like the one above I somehow have to replicate that behaviour for SVG.If I separately calculate the dimensions after the path has been converted then it will not be a single parse conversion which I am targeting

Comment: @ThomasW I am using a XSLT script for the conversion.

Comment: @RobertLongson duly noted. I will update my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the svg element with a div element, and set styles to the div element, then enlarge the svg size enough to render whole graphic.

```
<div style="overflow:visible; margin-left:121px; margin-top:39px; height:206px; width:327px;">
    <svg height="206px" width="500px">
        <path d=" M 244.3,102.7  A 82.3,52 0,0 0,82.3 102.7 L 1.3,102.7  A 163.3,102.7 0,0 1,325.3 102.7 L 325.3,102.7 365.8,102.7 284.8,153.3 203.8,102.7 244.3,102.7  L 244.3,102.7 " x="1.5" y="1.5" style="fill:#92d050; stroke-width:3; stroke:blue; "></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: excellent idea, though i might have to tweak it a little before I can use it but i can work with it. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName("path")[0].getBBox()` will get the bounds of the path (x, y, width, height) you can use those to set the `<svg>` element width and height.

Comment: Good answer but unfortunately my svg is generated server side. I cannot use `getBBox()` on the server without introducing some highly inefficient approach.

Comment: Why not call it on the client?

Comment: I need to create a purely HTML/CSS page without any javascript. It is the project requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the viewBox attribute of SVG. The viewBox tells the SVG is to take all the image that is being drawn within the viewBox and then apply width and height to it.

[Fiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VJL5W/1/)

```
<svg style="overflow:visible; margin-left:121px; margin-top:39px; " height="206"     width="327" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <path d=" M 244.3,102.7  A 82.3,52 0,0 0,82.3 102.7 L 1.3,102.7  A 163.3,102.7 0,0     1,325.3 102.7 L 325.3,102.7 365.8,102.7 284.8,153.3 203.8,102.7 244.3,102.7  L 244.3,102.7 " x="1.5" y="1.5" style="fill:#92d050; stroke-width:3; stroke:blue; "></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: viewbox does not effects anything outside the SVGs dimensions, it only shrinks or inflates the image to accomodate it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to Chrome seems make it work but I am not sure if your layout can accommodate wider SVG.  Have not tried in IE.

```
svg {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I can't use it. If there are other HTML elements that need to go next to the svg it will mess up their layout.